# How to match a string to a class name to name the logic more dynamic?

Tags: c#

Currently, this is my code. With certain conditions, it will use a different class. Although the method name is the same for both classes, the logic in it is completely different. Same product do no need attachment.

```
if (productName == "ProductA")
{
    ProductA.InsertAttachment(emailRequest);
}

if (productName == "ProductB")
{
    ProductB.InsertAttachment(emailRequest, message);
}
```

Is it possible to refactor the code by removing the if statement by checking the string? If the string match with a class name, it will directly use that class name and its method. As you can see the hardcoded value is the same as the class name.

Comment: I think you need to explain better whats your goal, there are some options to run a method according to a string value but its hard to understand what fits your goal

Comment: Do you really need different classes for product A and product B, instead of just having one Product class with two instances of Product representing product A and product B, respectively?

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace, each product will have its own attachment and the logic to get the attachment are unique to each product.

Comment: Same product do no need attachment

Comment: Check Reflection for your problem

Comment: Perhaps the `nameof(Class)` expression would help you? See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof

Comment: i would have a dictionary of string=>Action

Comment: @pm100, possible to use dictionary string => Action if the method definitions are different?

Comment: @Steve yes - you can have actions that do anything